# Android Studio not suggesting Firebase BoM new versions

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I am using firebase in my android app, and I have included several firebase client libraries in my `build.gradle`, each with its own version.

When a new version of each library was available, Android Studio suggested I upgrade the version to the newer version by highlighting the dependency in yellow.

I recently updated my `build.gradle` to use [Firebase BoM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more#bom), so that the BoM picks the compatible versions of the each firebase library, so I don't need to specify individual versions of each firebase library.

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
```

Now, Android Studio doesn't detect new versions of `firebase-bom`, as it did for individual firebase libraries earlier. For example, I can see that `26.1.1` of `firebase-bom` is released, but Android Studio doesn't show me that.

Why is this? Is there any way to get Android Studio to detect new versions of `firebase-bom`?

Comment: You'll probably need to file a feature/bug report with Android Studio.  The BoM itself isn't the issue.  Studio just doesn't know how to deal with them for the purpose of highlighting updates.

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using? I'm using 4.1 and this bug is still there.

Comment: Same problem here, with Android Studio "Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1"

Comment: 2022, I'm on latest version and still not suggesting. on the other hand, Firebase old version using deprecated libraries in old MOBs.

Comment: Sure, I always have to check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more#bom) of not localized one (= in English) for the latest BoM version.